# How to fit the paper-size to the content in beamer?

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles

How can I modify the page size (like standalone) to fit the contents here?
The included picture link is cited at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.3\paperwidth}
    % define source coordinates
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Apricot \& Peach \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-apri);
        \item Almond \& Aloe \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-almond);
        \item Rose \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-rose);
        \item Unscented \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-unscented);
        \item Lime \& Lemon \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-lime);
        \item Lavender \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-lavender);
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.45\paperwidth}
    \tikzstyle{background grid}=[draw, black!50,step=.5cm]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \node [inner sep=0pt,above right, yshift=1.5cm] 
            {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{daniells-pile}};
        % show origin
        \fill (0,0) circle (white,2pt);
        % define destination coordinates
        \path (1.6,1.5) coordinate (almond)
              (2.5,1.5) coordinate (rose)
              (.15,2) coordinate (apri)
              (3.5,1.5) coordinate (unscented)
              (4.5,1.5) coordinate (lime)
              (5.5,1.5) coordinate (lavender);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->,orange,thick] (s-apri) edge [out=20, in=180] (apri);
    \path[->,green,thick] (s-almond) edge [out=-120, in=-60] (almond);
    \path[->,red,thick] (s-rose) edge [out=-15, in=-60] (rose);
    \path[->,blue,thick] (s-unscented) edge [out=-10, in=-60] (unscented);
    \path[->,yellow,thick] (s-lime) edge [out=0, in=-60] (lime);
    \path[->,purple,thick] (s-lavender) edge [out=22, in=-60] (lavender);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In beamer it does IMHO not make too much sense to make the page larger because in the end you want to use it in a presentation, don't you? (Off-topic: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.)

Comment: If you make the page larger, you have to make the presentation wall larger as well.

Comment: You might try using `plain` for the frame i.e. `\begin{frame}[plain]`. If that's not enough, search the Beamer manual for 'evil` and find ways to compress things further. (The latter may not help here, though, since the image itself can't be squeezed.) If none of that works, why not change `6cm` to something smaller?

Comment: Hello : Is this question still open ?

Comment: @BambOo Still open.

Comment: @Reza, to be sure, what do you exactly mean by fit the contents ? When I compile your document, after a few corrections though, everything wokrs fine. I will post an partial answer below so you see what I corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a partial answer to serve as base for discussion with the OP**

Corrected MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{ % <--- corrected style definitions as "\tikzstyle" is superseeded by "\tikzset"
    every picture/.append style={remember picture},
    na/.style = {baseline=-.5ex},
}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.3\paperwidth}
    % define source coordinates
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Apricot \& Peach \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-apri);
        \item Almond \& Aloe \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-almond);
        \item Rose \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-rose);
        \item Unscented \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-unscented);
        \item Lime \& Lemon \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-lime);
        \item Lavender \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-lavender);
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.45\paperwidth}
    \tikzstyle{background grid}=[draw, black!50,step=.5cm]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \node [inner sep=0pt,above right, yshift=1.5cm] 
            {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{daniells-pile}};
        % show origin
        \fill[white] (0,0) circle (2pt); % <--- corrected color specification
        % define destination coordinates
        \path (1.6,1.5) coordinate (almond)
              (2.5,1.5) coordinate (rose)
              (.15,2) coordinate (apri)
              (3.5,1.5) coordinate (unscented)
              (4.5,1.5) coordinate (lime)
              (5.5,1.5) coordinate (lavender);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->,orange,thick] (s-apri) edge [out=20, in=180] (apri);
    \path[->,green,thick] (s-almond) edge [out=-120, in=-60] (almond);
    \path[->,red,thick] (s-rose) edge [out=-15, in=-60] (rose);
    \path[->,blue,thick] (s-unscented) edge [out=-10, in=-60] (unscented);
    \path[->,yellow,thick] (s-lime) edge [out=0, in=-60] (lime);
    \path[->,purple,thick] (s-lavender) edge [out=22, in=-60] (lavender);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

[image: r]